# CUBA Platform - Unable to Connect

Tags: cuba-platform

I have just begun using the CUBA Platform and was following the very [first tutorial video](https://www.cuba-platform.com/quick-start-part-1).

However, when I try to actually access the web application, I get an error in Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome, stating that it is "Unable to connect to localhost:8080."

This has happened on my home PC and my work PC.  I have tried searching the web for others having a similar issue, but have been unsuccessful.

I did also try "forcing" a secure connection with `https://` to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your operating system? Is there app.log file in deploy/tomcat/logs folder? If yes, please attach it here.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the exact same problem -- and it must be the time of night.

After an exhaustive search of the firewall rules on my laptop, settings in the system, etc. I found the problem.  Go to:

```
http://<ip address>:8080/app
```

I missed the '/app' on the address.